# How to check USER IP in django project when website loads?

Tags: python, django, request, ip

I am working on django website. I want make this website country restricted. So I want to check user ip when website is accessed. It doesn't matter what is url or which app is loaded. So if user is not from specific country, I want to show them error message that they cannot access this website.

I am using [GeoLitCity](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) database to get user's country. I know how to get user's ip. But I don't know how to do it in initialization step, before anything loads. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Write a middleware that returns an error page when th eIP should be blocked: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Thank you @KlausD. This might be helpful. I will look into this. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a [custom middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) `ValidateUserCountryMiddleware`**  which will check if the country from where the request was made is from a specific country or not. If the request is made from a valid country, then Django will process the request. Otherwise, it will return a `HttpResponseForbidden` response.

In our custom middleware class, we will define a `process_request()` method. It should return either `None` or an `HttpResponse` object.

From the docs on [`process_request()`:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process-request)

> If it returns `None`, Django will continue processing this request,
>   executing any other `process_request()` middleware, then, `process_view()`
>   middleware, and finally, the appropriate view. If it returns an
>   `HttpResponse` object, Django won’t bother calling any other request,
>   view or exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it’ll apply
>   response middleware to that `HttpResponse`, and return the result.

Here, we will  return a `HttpResponseForbidden` response in case the request did not come from a specified country.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden    

class ValidateUserCountryMiddleware(object):  
    """
    This custom middleware class will check the country from where the request
    was made using the IP address. If the country is valid, then Django will process
    the request. Otherwise, it will return a 403 forbidden response
    """

    def process_request(self, request):  
        # here write the logic to obtain the country from the IP address. 
        # Then check if its a valid country

        if not valid_country: # check if its a valid country 
            return HttpResponseForbidden('You cannot access the website from this location.') # dont't process the request and return 403 forbidden response

        return # return None in case of a valid request
```

Then add your middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py` file.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    # add your custom middleware here
    'my_project.middlewares.ValidateUserCountryMiddleware',

)
```